# Table doesnt have an ineteger as a primary key how to perform operations on it?

Tags: plsql

This question was asked in one practical exams at my university.
Q: A table has following columnheads/columns:

```
medicine_name,medicine_manufacture_date,medicine_expiry_date.
```

As the columnhead names describe they have the respective data about a medicine in them.
Now they asked to write a pl/sql block to make list of all medicines' names which have expired(i.e.current system date is greater than the expirydate values of the medicine).
I strongly think that the column of sequential consecutive integers(like 1,2,3,...n) must be added to the table, which will act as a primary key to each medicine name.Medicine names are unique but to perform iterative operations they should posses an integer primary key. 
Is it still possible to get the result without assigning an ineteger primary key?

I altered the table and assigned primary key to each record and wrote following block... It worked 
but i want to do it without assigning a primary key. All possible smart ways will be adored!Plz suggest correction of any type in my code... My code is as follows:

```
   declare
         a date;
         b date;
        diff number(10);
        medicine varchar(25);
   begin
              a:=sysdate;
                        for i in 1..5
               loop
                       select medicine_expiry_date into b from med_details where med_id=i ;
                            diff:=trunc(a-b);
                  if
                       diff>0  then
                            select medicine_name into medicine from med_details where med_id=i;
                                dbms_output.put_line(medicine);
                          end if;
             end loop;
  end;
  /
```

Comment: It is not necessary to have a integer primary key. Why do you think it is needed?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The following medicines have expired:');

  FOR aRow IN (SELECT MEDICINE_NAME
                 FROM MEDICINE
                 WHERE EXPIRY_DATE < SYSDATE)
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(aRow.MEDICINE_NAME);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

You could put an artificial primary key on this table if there was some need to have some other table refer to this one and no other practical candidate key was available, but it's not needed to answer the question as asked above.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: great it worked superb! m overwhelmed! Which book u studied from plz name it..Thank you!

Comment: I learned my PL/SQL by programming in it for many years.  As far as books go I like [the Oracle PL/SQL reference manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/toc.htm) and [the Oracle SQL reference manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/toc.htm).  Share and enjoy.

Comment: Thanks again dear Bob, i wish i could have a person like u as a GURU! I just edited my question and hav added my code, i will feel gud if u suggest me the improvement.. I hav started learning pl/sql a week before.

Answer (score 0):

It looks straightforward... I suspect that there are some extra details.

```
/*
Q: A table has following columnheads/columns: 
medicine_name,
medicine_manufacture_date,
medicine_expiry_date.

Now they asked to write a pl/sql block to make list of all medicines' names which have expired
(i.e.current system date is greater than the expirydate values of the medicine).
*/

-- SQL:

SELECT medicine_name
FROM a_table
WHERE medicine_expiry_date < SYSDATE;

-- PL/SQL v.1:

DECLARE
    TYPE medicine_ntt IS TABLE OF a_table%ROWTYPE;
    l_medicine  medicine_ntt;
BEGIN
    SELECT  medicine_name
    ,       medicine_expiry_date
    BULK    COLLECT INTO l_medicine
    FROM    a_table;

    FOR indx IN 1..l_medicine.COUNT LOOP
        IF l_medicine(indx).medicine_expiry_date < SYSDATE THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_medicine(indx).medicine_name);
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
END;

-- PL/SQL v.2:

DECLARE
    CURSOR medicine_cur IS
        SELECT  medicine_name
        ,       medicine_expiry_date
        FROM    a_table;

    TYPE medicine_ntt IS TABLE OF medicine_cur%ROWTYPE;
    l_medicine         medicine_ntt;
    l_medicine_expired medicine_ntt := medicine_ntt();
BEGIN
    OPEN  medicine_cur;
    FETCH medicine_cur BULK COLLECT INTO l_medicine;
    CLOSE medicine_cur;

    FOR indx IN 1..l_medicine.COUNT LOOP
        IF l_medicine(indx).medicine_expiry_date < SYSDATE THEN
            l_medicine_expired.EXTEND;
            l_medicine_expired(l_medicine_expired.LAST) := l_medicine(indx);
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

    FOR indx IN 1..l_medicine_expired.COUNT LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_medicine_expired(indx).medicine_name);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Thanx for the reply! Can u do it in some more compressed way!

Comment: @Deepeshkumar Take a look at "PL/SQL v.1"